# terraform 0.11 how to remove a key value pair from a map?

Tags: terraform

I have a map in a variable, var.fruits like below but I want to create a local map and remove the key value that matches oranges. So from the below map

```
{
  "oranges" = {
    "number" = "165"
    "name" = "oranges"
  },
  "apples" = {
    "number" = "200"
    "name" = "apples"
  }
}
```

I want to create the following map:

```
{
  "oranges" = {
    "number" = "165"
    "name" = "oranges"
  }
}
```

I've tried in terraform the following code

```
locals {
  new_fruit_map = {for k, v in var.fruits : k => v
    if k != "apples" }
}
```

but I'm getting the following error Error parsing on plan:

At 369:27: expected: IDENT | STRING | ASSIGN | LBRACE got: COMMA

Looks like a syntax issue but not sure what I'm missing :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terraform v0.11 is obsolete and this sort of operation is beyond the capabilities of that very old version of the Terraform language.

You can find a full description of all of the expression-related capabilities for Terraform v0.11 [in the old Terraform v0.11 documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/v1.1.x/configuration-0-11/interpolation). That page describes the full set of capabilities available to you for data manipulation in Terraform v0.11. In particular, notice that `for` expressions are not available in that version, and that all dynamic expressions must be presented using the string interpolation syntax.

I can think of one way to get something *similar* to what you described, but it isn't exact and it is rather inscrutible:

```
variable "fruits" {
  type = "map"
}

locals {
  filtered_fruits = "${merge(var.fruits, map("apples", {}))}"
}
```

The map of maps of strings you've described is actually beyond what Terraform v0.11 was designed to support: it only officially supported maps of strings. However, some parts of Terraform v0.11 did *accidentally* support nested maps, and so the above *might* work but I can't be sure since I don't have Terraform v0.11 installed to test.

This is different from what you asked for because instead of removing `"apples"` completely it will instead replace that element's value with an empty map, like this:

```
{
  "oranges" = {
    "number" = "165"
    "name" = "oranges"
  }
  "apples" = {}
}
```

Whether that's actually useful will depend on what you were intending to do with this transformed value.

I can't imagine any way to get closer to your desired result than this within the limitations of Terraform v0.11. I would strongly recommend upgrading to a modern version of Terraform if you need to deal with anything other than very simple direct resource declarations.